# Visual Studio 2008: Can't connect to known good TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

A freshly installed TFS 2010 is at `http://serverX:8080/tfs`.

A Windows 7 developer machine with VS 2008 Pro SP1 and the VS2008 Team Explorer (**no SP**). The [TFS 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9E40A5B6-DA41-43A2-A06D-3CEE196BFE3D&displaylang=en) didn't work for me - "None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer."

The developer machine is able to browse the TFS site at the above URL.

**The Issue** is around trying to add the TFS server into the Team Explorer window in Visual Studio 2008. Here's a screenshot showing the error:

> unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server. Possible reasons for failure include: The Team Foundation Server name, port number or protocol is incorrect. The Team Foundation Server is offline. Password is expired or incorrect.

The TFS server is up and running properly. Firewall ports are open, and **is accessible via the browser** on the dev machine!!

[image]
[larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLCxE.png)

**Question**: how can you connect from VS 2008 Pro to a TFS 2010 server?

**Resolution**

Here's how I solved this problem:

**Installations**

- install Visual Studio 2008
- install [VS 2008 Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en) as above.
- re-install [VS 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)
- install the [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CF13EA45-D17B-4EDC-8E6C-6C5B208EC54D&displaylang=en)  (VS90SP1-KB974558-x86.exe)

**Config**

- when adding a TFS server to Team Explorer, you **MUST** specify the URL as such:
  `http://[tfsserver]:[port]/[vdir]/[projectCollection]`
- in my case above, it was `http://serverX:8080/tfs/AppDev-TestProject`
- you cannot simply add the TFS server name and have VS look for all Project Collections on the server. TFS 2010 has a new URL (by default) and VS 2008 doesn't recognize how to gather that list.

Comment: I have to say TFS errors are always so descriptive, you know immediately what's wrong!

Comment: Thanks! I read the documentation, I added the "/tfS" but I did not realize that I also had to add "/tfs/tpc-name" until I read your post. /Gunnar

Comment: When you are dealing with forward compatability I would like to see anyone else do a better job ;)

Comment: Just a note that after installing VS 2008 SP1 you should install the post-SP1 hotfixes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164792/visual-studio-2008-hotfixes

Comment: +1 Thanks!. If in doubt about the URL, get the URL from a working connected VS2010 . In my case it was `http://servername:8080/DefaultCollection`

Comment: In case someone is looking at this to connect to a newer version of TFS install the forward compatibility update for TFS 2012 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983 Works fine with TFS 2015.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check out this article '[Connecting VS2008 to any TFS2010 Project Collection](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2009/05/26/connecting-vs2008-to-any-tfs2010-project-collection.aspx)'.

The only catch here is that the author didn't mention that you need to install/reinstall Service Pack 1 '[Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)' for Visual Studio 2008 after installing Team Explorer 2008. This will take care of the invalid characters error message when trying to connect.

Comment: Thanks Bert; I had not seen that blogpost. I will update the question with the things-to-do for future searchers.

Comment: Updated blog post that lists  all versions of Visual Studio since 2005 in combination with all versions of TFS since 2010: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html

Comment: @Bert Your link is bad T.T

Comment: The first link is no longer available =(

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised no one here has mentioned the [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CF13EA45-D17B-4EDC-8E6C-6C5B208EC54D&displaylang=en).  I followed the directions above, but still was unable to connect; Installing the Forward Compatibility Patch finally let me connect.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Updated the my 'resolution' in the question.

Answer (score 4):

To **Connect Visual Studio 2008 to a TFS2010 server** this is what it took for me to connect: Install TFS plugin; install VS2008SP1; install TFS compatibility update. Before I did this I was getting an error tf3002 Here are some details:

1. Install Team Explorer 2008 from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86. It's an iso file so I used MagicISO to mount it. After this when the source control options (Tools --> Options --> Source Control) will have TFS in drop down in addition to VSS.

2 Install VS2008SP1 - Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E

3 Install Compatibility Update - Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010 from [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d)

Also when I opened the Connect to TFS window (Tools --> Connect to TFS). After I entered in the complete path such as `http://YourServerName:8080/so/TFSProjects` including the http://. Also I noticed that when it's installed correctly on the Add TFS window when the http:// is typed in the Port # txtbox will be disabled. 
This question helped me & I Hope this answer helps.

[image]

Comment: After installing the 3 software updates, use the full path syntax for the Team Foundation Server Name:

http://MyServerName:8080/tfs/defaultcollection