# Visual Studio 2008 Hotfixes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, patch

I am installing Visual Studio 2008 on a new machine and I cannot find a list of all the HotFixes that have been released. I am planning on installing SP1 but I remember putting about 5 other patches on there. Does anyone have a list of patches that need to be installed? If not maybe we can start a list.

Based on this list I installed SP1 and the following patches in this order:

- KB957259 - C# Background compilation causes bogus errors in ASP.NET
- KB958017 - Rollup Hotfix for several issues in WPF designer Visual Studio 2008
- KB957912 - Update for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Debugging and Breakpoints
- KB967631 - Update for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Debugger
- KB960075 - VS Dev Environment crash after undocking windows or changing layouts
- KB963035 - VS2008 SP1 sometimes hangs irretrievably after WPF Designer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Hotfix%2cVisual%20Studio%202008

Comment: if someone's looking for the hotfix for KB960075 and/or KB957912 you can find it [here](http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/Microsoft/VS2008/) (KB960075 signature matches the one presented [here](http://www.herdprotect.com/vs90sp1-kb960075-v2-x86.exe-1f8786339e7b3d64683b693bce1700c06fde3836.aspx). Haven't checked the other)