# Can't to connect Visual Studio 2008 to TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I am trying to connect to my TFS 2010 RC server.  When I try to connect I get a error message.

Here is a screen shot:

[alt text http://xs.to/image-2537_4B8BEAA0.jpg](http://xs.to/image-2537_4B8BEAA0.jpg)

This is the path I am using to connect: `http://tfs2010test:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

I have Team Explorer 2008 SP 1 installed.

I have read this question: [Visual Studio 2008: Can't connect to known good TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925512/visual-studio-2008-cant-connect-to-known-good-tfs-2010-beta-2).  That is how I got my path that I tried.

I can connect just fine using Visual Studio 2010.

What am I missing?

Comment: On the referenced question, have you seen the answer by Ahmad Mageed, pointing out the reinstallation of the SP1 AFTER the Team Explorer?

Comment: Yeah.  I am always careful to add them in the right order. Turns out there was a forward compatibility piece I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed the forward compatibility update from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d)?  Further details can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/10/19/compatibility-matrix-for-2010-beta-2-team-foundation-server-to-team-explorer-2008-and-2005.aspx).

Comment: That was what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Does visual studio SP1 have to be installed after the forward compatibility update to Team Explorer 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution to get Visual Studio 2008 Team System to connect to TFS2010: (Beware convoluted).

1. Install Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer
2. Uninstall Office 2007 (because of an incompatibility between Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installer and Office 2007)
3. Run the Microsoft Install Clean Up utility to remove all references to Office 2007 that did not get removed when uninstalling)
4. Re-Install Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
5. Install Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update for Team Foundation Server 2010
6. Reinstall Office 2007 or go to OpenOffice
7. Access TFS2010 repository...

Answer (score 0):

When I have added TFS servers before, I could not add the port in the URL. Have you tried this without the port, and allow discovery?

Comment: I tested this as well as I can, without simulating your environment. I received an error that I may not include "http" or "/" in the server name edit box. This was a different error message than you are showing however.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- Have you tried connecting with Team Explorer 2010?
- Have you tried creating a new project collection?
- On your server, open the TFS admin tool and confirm that you have permissions to use that collection.

Be aware, some options are just not available in Team Explorer 2008.

Let me know if you need help with the security/groups on the server.  It was very confusing to me when I first tried to work with it.

Comment: I can connect with Team Explorer 2010.  I have made a new project collection and I can't connect to that either.  As for the permissions, If I can connect using 2010 then  should be fine with 2008 too right?