# Windows 8.1 64 + Visual Studio 2008 + Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, windows-8.1, x86-64, team-explorer

I am trying to set up the environment described in the subject (Windows 8.1 64 + Visual Studio 2008 + Team Explorer) for a project that's using some particular component that require vs2008 (license issue I guess)

I have followed every single step-by-step guide I have found here at stackOverflow or out there but couldn't solve it yet. The point seems to be that some of the patches needed are not available (or I was not able to find them) for 64 bit systems. In particular VS90SP1-KB974558-x86 and VS90sp1-KB945140-ESN.

So, before I downgrade to Windows 8 32bit or even to Windows 7 32bit, is there a version for the patches for 64 systems or an alternative method?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of TFS are you using? e.g. TFS2012 needs VS2010 with sp1, that SP you've linked to only gets you to TFS2010, is that what you want?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. Didn't mention TFS version is 2010.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925512/visual-studio-2008-cant-connect-to-known-good-tfs-2010 ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and is the usual approach to the problem.

I finally "solved" the problem by downgrading my O.S. to a 32 bit one. I was then able to install every patch and connect to tfs.

Thanks for your attention.