# MSSCCI provider for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have Team Foundation Server 2015 installed, and I'm trying to connect Visual Studio 2008 (Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE) to the team project.  I have installed VS 2008 Team Explorer (version 9.0.21022.8).

[According to MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements), this should be possible using MSSCCI Provider.  However, I can't find the version that's compatible with TFS 2015.

**Question:  Where is the MSSCCI Provider for TFS 2015, or is there another way to connect VS 2008 to TFS 2015 ?**

I have tried MSSCCI Provider for TFS 2013, and it failed because it didn't detect TFS 2013 (which makes sense since I have 2015 installed).

Comment: There is a forward compatibility update for TFS 2012 (link in Isaiah4110 answer), but basically nothing has changed since TFS 2010 follow instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925512/visual-studio-2008-cant-connect-to-known-good-tfs-2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Did you install the vs2008 sp1 compatibility GDR?  Or else please install it.. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983
2. When passing the TFS URL in VS 2008 make sure that you are passing the tfs collection name as well, otherwise vs 2008 will throw error. For example, http://servername:8080/tfs/{collection1}

Edit: Please make sure that you install VS 2008 SP1 before you try steps 1 and 2.

Comment: The vs2008 compatibility link you provided in #1 is an older version of the MSSCCI I tried for TFS 2013.  Your link is for TFS 2012.  I'm assuming it will also fail because I don't have TFS 2012 installed, but I will go ahead and give it a shot later today.  And regarding #2, yes, I tried passing the collection name.  It throws an error because of the "/" (which is an issue resolved by the MSSCCI, I assume).

Comment: I tried the GDR and it won't even attempt to install because I don't have TFS 2012.

Comment: You dont need TFS 2012 to install this GDR, check the requirements tab in the above link. That being said, have you installed VS 2008 SP1? That is a pre-requirement to install the GDR. The GDR will fix the "/" in the URL issue, we had the same issue when we moved to TFS 2013.

Comment: Once I installed VS SP1, I was able to install the GDR and connect to TFS.

Comment: super its the complete url along with collection name where the core resolution is, and yes the same thing works for TFS 2015 On Premises server

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had no VS 2008 IDE was installed until yesterday. 
Due to some conversion limitations in my company, I had to install the old Visual Studio 2008 to my office PC (Windows 10 Pro x64) and connect it to TFS 2015.

I hope this helps someone else like me:

1. First I've installed Visual Studio 2008.
2. And then VS 2008 SP1.
3. Lastly Visual Studio TeamExplorer 2008. (At least this should be the happy ending but I was wrong.)
4. Tried to install VS90SP1-KB974558-x86, but it failed. The package seeks for VS 2008 SP1. I think TeamExplorer 2008 overrides sth important for KB974558.
5. Installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 again.
6. VS90SP1-KB974558-x86 installed successfully.
7. On the page "Connect to Team Foundation Server", add your TFS 2015 server by ignoring the port and protocol section, and write down your own like;

> http://TFS_SERVER:PORT_NUMBER/tfs/TFS_COLLECTION_NAME

It fails everytime if I skip the collection name part.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant comment. I want to say that we have the same problem.

What works is installing the Visual Studio Team Explorer 2013 which includes a Visual Studio Shell 2013 and then we can install the MSSCCI Provider 2013. But thats just a workaround.

We also wonder where the MSSCCI Provider for 2015 is.

Comment: Just curious - is there a particular reason you want a TFS 2015 MSSCCI provider, instead of just using the TFS 2013 MSSCCI provider? Are there problems / missing functionality with the TFS 2013 MSSCCI provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use MSSCCI for TFS 2013 to connect to TFS2015 source control in VS2008.

Just as the MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements) shown, in VS2008, **Version Control** is available via using MSSCCI Provider. So instead of connect to TFS in Team Explorer, you need to go to File -> Source Control -> Open from Source Control -> Connect to Team Foundation Server. I believe this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2014/01/23/connecting-to-team-foundation-server-2013-using-visual-studio-2005-thru-msscci-provider.aspx) is helpful to you (although it is written for TFS2013 with VS2005, it applies to TFS2015 with VS2008).

Comment: I can't install MSSCCI for TFS 2013 because I don't have TFS 2013 installed.  Or are you suggesting I install TFS 2013 in order to install MSSCCI for TFS 2013?

Comment: @devlincarnate, no you don't need to install TFS2013 in order to install MSSCCI. In other words, TFS is not a pre-requirement to install MSSCCI. Do you get any errors when install it?

Comment: I don't get any errors.  I get a message stating that TFS 2013 isn't installed.

Comment: You do not need TFS 2013 installed, but you do need the TFS 2013 client object model. The TFS 2013 client OM is included with Visual Studio 2013, which is required. Are you able to install one of the VS 2013 SKUs (for instance, Visual Studio Team Explorer 2013) and then try to install the TFS 2013 MSSCCI?