# Connect from VS2005 to TFS2015 connection

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2005, tfs-2015

I'm using VS2005. My Version Control/Source code is in VSS till today. I want to shift my source to TFS 2015. **How to Connect to TFS2015 from VS2005**. I don't want to migrate my Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2005 is not supported with TFS 2015 so you may have to upgrade the VS

[TFS2015 compatibility with Visual Studio Versions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements)

VS2008 Could do that probably.

[VS2008 to TFS Connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083806/msscci-provider-for-visual-studio-2008-sp1-and-tfs-2015/32115218#32115218)

I've seen an option MSSCCI Provider for TFS 2015. Will drill down more & update on this.

Comment: I see the MSSCCI Provider for TFS 2015 is through VS2008. How about the same with VS2005 ?

Comment: I've tried to install MSSCCI Provided with VS2005. It throws error saying "Visual studio 2013 team explorer is not installed or configured". VS2005 couldn't be configured to TFS2015. 

Obviously, VS needs be upgraded.